# Apache2 won't start, doesn't exist?

Tags: apache2

Running on Ubuntu 14.04, I've attempted to install Apache with: `sudo apt-get install apache2`. This is successful I then type `sudo service apache2 start`. Nothing happens at all. When I navigate to http://localhost:80, I get a 500 error and the nginx version.

`service apache2 status` returns nothing. I've searched up and down for any processes called apache, and there is nothing.

How can I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 2):

If your getting an nginx error message at port 80, then nginx is already running there; Apache won't start. Stop nginx then Apache will work, or configure one of the servers to use a different port.

The exact steps you should take depend on whether you want to retain nginx.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer running apache2 than nginx, first you can stop nginx service.

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Then start apache2 webserver service again.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Mostly default web server is running on port 80.